# getActivity() in adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm loading ads in `onClick` of `RecyclerView`'s adapter.

In fragment it is perfectly working in this code:
`interstitialAd.loadAd(GDPR.getAdRequest(getActivity()));`

But in adapter it is not working in these method I tried:
`mInterstitialAd.loadAd(GDPR.getAdRequest(context));`

I also tried this but it is not working:
`mInterstitialAd.loadAd(GDPR.getAdRequest(this));`

`GDPR.getAdRequest`'s code is:

```
public static AdRequest getAdRequest(Activity activity) {
    return new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, GDPR.getBundleAd(activity))
        .build();
}
```

this is adapter's code:

```java
public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.VideosViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private Video[] data;
    private int layout;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public VideosAdapter(Context context, Video[] data, int layout) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VideosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout,null);
        return new VideosViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VideosViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Video selectedItem = data[position];
        holder.videoTitle.setText(selectedItem.getVideoTitle());
        holder.videoCategoryTitle.setText(selectedItem.getCategoryName());
        if (selectedItem.getVideoType().equals("0")){
            String thumbImg = Constants.SERVER_IMG_FIRST + selectedItem.getVideoThumb();
            Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(thumbImg)).into(holder.videoThumb);
        }else {
            // Get V and display img
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(selectedItem.getVideoUrl());
            String videoId = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
            String thumbYtImg = Constants.YOUTUBE_IMG_FIRST + videoId + Constants.YOUTUBE_IMG_BACK;
            Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(thumbYtImg)).into(holder.videoThumb);
        }
        String thumbCat = Constants.SERVER_IMG_FIRST + selectedItem.getCategoryThumb();
        Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(thumbCat)).into(holder.videoCategoryThumb);
        holder.videoInfoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Constants.SETTINGS.getAdmob().equals("1")){
                    Constants.ADS_COUNT++;
                    if (Constants.ADS_COUNT>=Integer.valueOf(Constants.SETTINGS.getAdmobIntrestitialAdDisplayAfter())){
                        Constants.ADS_COUNT = 0;
                        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
                        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(Constants.SETTINGS.getAdmobIntrestitialId());
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(GDPR.getAdRequest(context));

                        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdLoaded() {
                                super.onAdLoaded();
                                if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                                toDoOnInfoBtnClicked(position,data);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdClosed() {
                                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                                toDoOnInfoBtnClicked(position,data);
                            }
                        });


                    }else{
                        toDoOnInfoBtnClicked(position,data);
                    }

                }else{
                    toDoOnInfoBtnClicked(position,data);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public class VideosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView videoTitle,videoCategoryTitle;
        public VideosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            videoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            videoCategoryTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_category_title);

        }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have a problem in the Adapter class. If you show the Adapter's code, someone can give you a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Is the add is not being shown? Or you are getting a crash? Can you please post the error that you see in your logcat please? Thank you!

Comment: @ReazMurshed red underlined error is showing.

Comment: I am not quite sure.. Where exactly do you see the error? It would be great if you could post a screenshot.

Comment: @ReazMurshed this is the error: ```getAdRequest(android.app.Activity) in GDPR cannot be applied into (android.Context.context)``` runtime error

Comment: Can you post the code where you are creating the adapter object?

Comment: @AdityaKurkure it is showing ```getAdRequest(android.app.Activity) in GDPR cannot be applied into (android.Context.context)``` when hovering in error when i try to do screenshot it disappears. i mean the box which came when hovering disappears,

Comment: casting context with activity worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because you are sending `Context` object to the method `getAdRequest(Activity activity)` which needs `Activity` object. So you can fix it in 2 ways

1. Change adapter to take `Activity` not `Context`. like below

   ```
   public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.VideosViewHolder> {
   private Activity activity;
   ..

   public VideosAdapter(Activity activity, Video[] data, int layout) {
       this.activity = activity;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. The second way to fix this is, change `getAdRequest(Activity activity)`, like below

   ```
   public static AdRequest getAdRequest(Context context) {
   return new AdRequest.Builder()
       .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, GDPR.getBundleAd(context))
       .build();
   }
   ```

But in the second way, I am not sure if `GDPR.getBundleAd()` can take context. So better to go with 1st way

---

3rd way is to typecast context as `Activity` as you commented. Like

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(GDPR.getAdRequest((Activity) context));
```

But there is one problem in this approach. As the constructor of your adapter take `Context` parameter, any Activity which using this adapter can create the object like `new VideosAdapter(activity, ...)` *BUT can create the object like `new VideosAdapter(applicationContext, ...)` or `new VideosAdapter(objectOfcontext, ...)`. So in the last 2 cases, you will get a typecast exception.*

Comment: it worked for me ```mInterstitialAd.loadAd(GDPR.getAdRequest((Activity) context));``` 
using Activity instead of context may affect other activity linked wtih that adapter.
I'd love to to tick your answer if you put that coz idea is from you

Comment: @madan Yes it will work till you are creating adapter object by passing Activity. see my edited answer with one problem with the approach. But till you are passing activity to create adpater object, this approach is fine

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an Activity object to your adapter. otherwise you'll face with that error.
use like this :

```
adapter = new VideosAdapter(YourActivity.this,yourData,R.layout.some_layout);
```